# How to increment score in Javascript RPS before ending game?

Tags: javascript

I am working on the Odin RPS game that determines the winner based on the first to 5 wins. I have a function that declares the winner via an alert after they hit 5 wins, however, the alert message pops up first and declares the winner before the score increments to its final display of 5 wins. Can anyone explain why? I have the gameEnd function after the keepScore function. I also tried adding the keepScore function within each result of the gamePlay function but the alert always displays first declaring the winner before the score increments to 5. I also have to click the game again to get the counter to reset the scores to 0 when the function tells it to reset to 0 when the gameEnd function runs. JS code below (also I know the winner is always declared the computer. I will change this after I get the function working...)

```
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const computerChoice = document.getElementById("computerChoice")
const playerChoice = document.getElementById("playerChoice")
const result = document.getElementById("result")
const playerScoreCum = document.getElementById("playerScore")
const computerScoreCum = document.getElementById("computerScore")
let playerSelection
let computerSelection
let results
const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button.btn[data-selection]')

possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    playerSelection = e.target.getAttribute('data-selection');
    playerChoice.textContent = playerSelection;
    computerPlay();
    gamePlay();
    keepScore();
    gameEnd();
}))

function computerPlay () {
    let computerOptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    computerSelection = computerOptions [Math.floor(Math.random() * computerOptions.length)];
    computerChoice.textContent = computerSelection
}

function gamePlay () {

    if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors")
        {
        results =  "You won!";
        ++playerScore;
        }
    else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper")
        { 
        results =  "You lost!";
        ++computerScore;
        }
    else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors")
        { 
        results =  "You lost!";
        ++computerScore;
        }
    else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock")
        { 
        results =  "You won!";
        ++playerScore;
        }
    else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper")
        {  
        results =  "You won!";
        ++playerScore;
        }
    else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock")
        { 
        results =  "You lost!";
        ++computerScore;
        }
    else {results =  "It's a tie!!!"}
    
   
}

function keepScore () {
    result.textContent = results
    playerScoreCum.textContent = playerScore
    computerScoreCum.textContent = computerScore

}


function gameEnd () {
    if (playerScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
        playerScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0
        alert("Computer won the game!!!")
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a hacky workaround for that - you could use `setTimeout(gameEnd, 0)` where you are calling the `gameEnd` function. I haven't myself tried it yet though. This is because `setTimeout()` itself gets called synchronously, and placed on the callstack right after keepScore().

Comment: `alert` stops the browser from running a paint cycle (probably browser dependent). I would suggest not using `alert` at all. Just show it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hacky workaround for that - you could use `setTimeout(gameEnd, 0)` where you are calling the `gameEnd` function. This is because `setTimeout()` itself gets called synchronously, and placed on the callstack right after `keepScore()`.

I haven't myself tried this yet though.